# How do I import a plotly graph within a python script?

Tags: python, numpy, png, plotly

Is there any API call to import a plotly graph as a .png file within an existing python script? If so, what is it?

For example, having just created a graph using the plotly module for python...

```
py.plot([data0, data1], layout = layout, filename='foo', fileopt='overwrite')
```

...is there a way of retrieving that graph as a .png within the same python script?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is.

First, update to the latest version of the plotly python package with

```
 $ pip install plotly --upgrade
```

Then, something like

```
 >>> import plotly.plotly as py 
 >>> py.sign_in('your-username','your-api-key')
 >>> data = [{'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[1,4,9]}] 
 >>> url = py.plot(data, filename='some-data')  # gen. online plot
 >>> py.image.save_as(data, 'some-data.png')    # gen. png plot
```

For more:

- https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/
- https://plot.ly/python/get-requests/

Comment: To find what to enter in place of `'your-api-key'`, log in at https://plot.ly and then visit https://plot.ly/settings/api.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution: add `.png` to any public plotly graph, e.g.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://plot.ly/~chris/1638.png')
```

This works for any public plotly graph. `.png`, `.svg`, `.pdf` are supported.

`.py`, `.jl`, `.json`, `.m`, `.r`, `.js` can be used to view the code could regenerate the graph (more here: http://blog.plot.ly/post/89402845747/a-graph-is-a-graph-is-a-graph)